# How to add a filter by category option using Django filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-filter

Hai i am trying to add a filter option by category on django using Django filter. But when i am trying to add a filter i got an error saying that

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'blogs'.
```

Can anyone please help me to create a filter by category.

This is my blog model

```
class blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, auto_created=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Categorie', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is my category model

```
class Categorie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, auto_created=True)
```

This is my filters.py file

```
blog_choice = (
    ('new','new'),
    ('latest','latest'),
    ('technology','technology'),
    ('sports','sports'),
)

category = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(label='Category', choices=blog_choice,  widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'mr-2 h-[15px] w-5 border-gray-300 inline mb-4 '}))
```

I tried to create a filter function but got error

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'new'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You filter on the `slug` or the `name` of the category, so you should filter on the `category__slug` or `category__name`:

```
category = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
    label='Category',
    choices=blog_choice,
    widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        attrs={'class': 'mr-2 h-[15px] w-5 border-gray-300 inline mb-4 '}
    ),
    field_name='category__slug',
)
```